# How to set title and main matter pages independently, with memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, titles

I am setting up the page layout using memoir commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{10mm}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

This does not work properly (influences headers only). The correct way, if I recall correctly, is to put the commands before `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\setlrmarginsandblock{20mm}{10mm}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

This works fine. However, if I want to have different margins on the cover and in the main text, how can I achieve it? I need to call \setlrmarginsandblock after `\begin{document}` and then it does not work again.

Comment: I'd set the layout for the main document, and the either make the cover separately, og have a look at `\calccentering` which can be combined with `adjustwidth` to center the cover compared to the paper, not the margins

Comment: @daleif, thanks, and if you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(just a copy of my comment)

I'd set the layout for the main document, and the either make the cover separately, og have a look at `\calccentering` which can be combined with adjustwidth to center the cover compared to the paper, not the margins